# What does it mean when there is only one variable in a single line in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script

When I read some PineScript code, I come across this:

```
pDir = 1        
if array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 1
        pDir := array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, 0)/
        pDir := pDir % 2 == 0 ? pDir / 2 : pDir
        pDir
```

In the last line, there is only one variable. So, What does it mean when there is only one variable in a single line in PineScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does nothing. You can remove it and the result will be the same.

Comment: You need to specify this is only true in this specific case. The last value is the one that will be returned when a function call returns to the caller. This function works with a single variable, this is why the last line can be removed, but for complex functions it is not straightforward what you want to return. Most of the case you don't want to calculate anything after the value you want to send back is calculated, but there can be cases when you calculate 2 values and based on some condition you want to send back one of them.

Comment: @karatedog So for this block of code, we assume there are still multiple lines of code after the 'if' statement. When the condition of the 'if' statement (array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 1)is true , then the variable pDir is given other values, then pDir will be returned even if there are other code after this 'if' statement? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Well, in short, yes, that is correct. However Pine has some issues, so I always do a variable assignment with IF (so I don't put the variable assignment into the IF and ELSE block, but I assign the return value of the IF/ELSE block to a variable (can't properly give an example in a comment), which is much more stable.

Comment: @karatedog Can you maybe give an example of this issue using pastebin?

Comment: @vitruvius https://pastebin.com/29Mk9x3P , spaces gone wild, especially the 4 spaces under IF

Comment: @karatedog Got it. Thank you very much for your answer and example......Do you know how to accept your answer as the correct or most helpful answer when your answer is in other people's answer comments?

Comment: @QIANG: no need to, I'm not a reputation hunter :-)